# htaccess directory management

Tags: .htaccess

im going to ask a really simple question. i dont want my link to show this when i run my page :

```
http://localhost/example/assets/gallery.php
```

what i want is :

```
http://localhost/example/assets/
```

so how to do it in .htaccess file ?

i would really appreciate it if you can help because im so confused after reading forums .

my htaccess is like this right now but you know it only helps to remove extension :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file currently located?

Comment: Hello @MrWhite ! it is located to root directory and i moved my files from assets so they are in root too i just want to fix this i kept digging but i keep failing i really need concrete example for this , i have seen many things about extension but i want the whole gallery.php or index.php file to be hidden

Answer (score 1):

### How to make assets/gallery.php -> assets/

---

1. In the `assets` folder make a `.htaccess` file
2. Paste in this code :

   ```
   DirectoryIndex gallery.php
   ```

This code changes the Directory Index (like a `index.php` file) to the `gallery.php` file meaning `gallery.php` is now like the `index.php` file.

Comment: can i create 2 htaccess files ? one in root and other in assets ?

Comment: Yep, you can create 100 htaccess if you want, when you create one in the assets directory it will only effect in the assets folder. So simply make a assets/.htaccess and then put in DirectoryIndex gallery.php

Comment: when i do that pages dont work , saying they dont exist . and i will need to do it for each page so im going to have to seperate to folders all php files ? and do i miss something i created htaccess in assets folder to and put that code in it

Answer (score 1):

The `DirectoryIndex` method that @RyanTheGhost suggests in his answer should have worked for the specific example you posted (where you request a *directory* and are serving a file from within that directory). However, the mod_rewrite directives you currently have in the document root<sup>1</sup> will conflict with any requests for directories<sup>2</sup> (although the `DirectoryIndex` should take priority).

However, the `DirectoryIndex` method is not very practical if you have many such files. And if you are not requesting a *directory* then this method naturally won't work anyway.

You could instead rewrite the URL using mod_rewrite in your existing `.htaccess` file, *before* your current directives.

<sup>1</sup> I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

For example:

```
# Rewrite "/example/assets/" to "/example/assets/gallery.php"
RewriteRule ^example/assets/$ example/assets/gallery.php [L]
```

Or, to avoid repitition:

```
# Rewrite "/example/assets/" to "/example/assets/gallery.php"
RewriteRule ^example/assets/$ $0gallery.php [L]
```

Where the `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `example/assets/` in this case. NB: There is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* or the *substitution* string.

Note that since you are requesting a directory (ie. `/example/assets/`) you need to ensure there is no DirectoryIndex document in that directory (eg. `index.html` or `index.php`), otherwise this will be served (by mod_dir) instead, overriding your internal rewrite above.

---

<sup>2</sup> Your current directives that append the `.php` extension are arguably incorrect:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

This rule appends the `.php` extension to any request that does not map to a physical file, even if the file with a `.php` extension does not exist either. This can result in the incorrect URL being reported back to the user in the 404 error document (depending on how this is implemented). For example, the default Apache 404 error document will report that `/foo.php` does not exist, when the user requested `/foo`.

This rule will also rewrite directories (since they are "not files") which will result in a 404 (as opposed to a 403 or directory listing, if enabled). Although a DirectoryIndex document will override this.

Additionally, the `NC` flag is superfluous and there is no need to backslash-escape the literal dot inside a character class.

You could instead check that the corresponding `.php` file exists before rewriting, instead of checking that the requested URL does not map to a file.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The request is now only rewritten when the corresponding `.php` file exists, which naturally avoids any conflicts with directories.

Comment: i got rid of my codes and added yours unfortunately it didnt work , or is it because im trying it at localhost  ? besides i moved my php files to root directory now because i just want it to be successful